# Stored Procedure.. using sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

Can any tell me how to send the LIst of IDs to the stored procedure in sql.

I need to send the List from My Controller so that that List of ID's can execute at a time using stored procedure.

Thanks

Comment: i think you might need some more information here.  what are you planning on doing with these ids?  are they to go into a where clause?

Comment: Yes nathan, its going to where clause.to update perticular Ids in the tables. using this sP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 and up you can use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: also helpful, here is a link showing how to call it from .net http://dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=47

Comment: @nathan gonzalez Sorry, I thought that link had an example - I've been doing a bit of those TVPs lately myself.  This link has a better complete overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Comment: that msdn link does have a good range of examples, but the last one regarding the streaming option is a bit terse. I wrote an article specifically detailing the streaming option here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/66554/ (registration is required).

Answer (score 3):

The best way (in 2008) is to pass it as a table.  Pre 2008 you had to use a CSV format VarChar then split it out.

Have a read of this: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: For 2005 (and even 2000), XML is usually the better way then CSV. Cleaner and faster, and easily extensible to multiple columns. From the article you link to: "In fact, XML is the fastest method that does not require any preparations in the server: you don't have to activate the CLR and create a function, nor do you need to define a table type for a table-valued parameter."

Answer (score 1):

What about a comma delimited string of Id's?

The problem is sql server doesn't support an array data type (or similar)

Comment: yes we can send string of id's but how to seperate those string of ids' with comma delimited in the sp.

Comment: Looks like Rene147 has added a useful link

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need something along the lines of this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split_String]
(
    @ConcatValues VARCHAR(MAX)
)  
RETURNS @Values Table 
(
     Value VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS  
/**************************************************************************************************************
Purpose:    When called from a stored procedure and passed a character delimited parameter (of String data type values), 
            this function returns a table named "@Values" with a field named "Value" (populated with the parameter list)
            which can then be referenced in the stored procedure.
            This function requires that the delimited paramater have as its first character the delimiter character.

Sample calls: 
            Select * from [dbo].[Split_String](';dog;cat;mouse')
            Select * from [dbo].[Split_String]('| dog| cat| mouse|')        
            Select * from [dbo].[Split_String]('|')     
            Select * from [dbo].[Split_String]('')      

**************************************************************************************************************/

BEGIN 
    --Indexes to keep the position of searching
    DECLARE @Delim CHAR(1)
    Declare @Pos1 Int
    Declare @Pos2 Int

    --Identify delimiter character
    SET @Delim = SUBSTRING(@ConcatValues, 1, 1)
    --Append delimiter character
    Set @ConcatValues = @ConcatValues + ' ' + @Delim    
    --Set 1st character of 1st value
    Set @Pos2 = 2

    While @Pos2 < Len(@ConcatValues)
    BEGIN
        Set @Pos1 = CharIndex(@Delim, @ConcatValues, @Pos2)
        Insert @Values SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(@ConcatValues, @Pos2, @Pos1 - @Pos2)))
        --Go to next non-delimiter character
        Set @Pos2 = @Pos1 + 1
    END
    RETURN
END


GO
```

Our split function is generic for use in a wide variety of situations and is dependent on the delimiter being identified by the first character in the string.  It is likely that it could be simplified a bit if you only need it in one spot.